# Elixir-Phoenix Association with custom primary_key throws Postgres Error: (invalid_foreign_key) there is no unique constraint matching given keys

Tags: postgresql, elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I have a `User` model created on this migration:

```
def change do
  create table(:users, primary_key: false) do
    add :name, :string
    add :email, :string
    add :address, :string, primary_key: true # blockchain type address

    timestamps()
  end

  create unique_index(:users, [:address])
end
```

Defined like this:

```
defmodule MyApp.Store.User do
  use Ecto.Schema
  import Ecto.Changeset

  @primary_key {:address, :string, autogenerate: false}
  @derive {Phoenix.Param, key: :address}

  schema "users" do
    field :name, :string
    field :email, :string

    has_many :games, MyApp.Store.Game

    timestamps()
  end

  @doc false
  def changeset(user, attrs) do
    user
    |> cast(attrs, [:name, :address])
    |> validate_required([:address])
    |> unique_constraint(:address)
  end
end
```

And a `Game` model that should have a one_to_many association with it, using `address` as the primary_key.

Created  on this migration:

```
def change do
    create table(:games) do
      add :name, :string, null: false
      add :user_address, references(:users, column: :address, type: :string, on_delete: :nothing), null: false
      add :description, :string

      timestamps()
    end

    create index(:games, [:user_address])
  end
```

Definition here:

```
defmodule MyApp.Store.Game do
  use Ecto.Schema
  import Ecto.Changeset

  schema "games" do
    field :name, :string
    field :description, :string

    belongs_to :user, MyApp.Store.User,
      foreign_key: :user_address,
      references: :address,
      type: :string,
      primary_key: true

    timestamps()
  end

  @doc false
  def changeset(game_bet, attrs) do
    game_bet
    |> cast(attrs, [:name, :description])
    |> validate_required([:name])
  end
end
```

Running migrations works fine, but when i try to run the tests (or the server) I get the following error:

```
** (Postgrex.Error) ERROR 42830 (invalid_foreign_key) there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "users"
```

Comment: [`@foreign_key_type :string`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Schema.html#module-schema-attributes)?

Comment: nope, didn't make a difference. Thanks anyway @AlekseiMatiushkin

Comment: The only thing odd I see is setting `primary_key: true` on the `user_address` field. That is creating a primary key like `(id, user_address)`.

Answer (score 0):

Your foreign key reference should look something like this:

```
add :address_id, references(address)
```

I found the definition you used a little strange:

```
add :address, :string, primary_key: true
```